# Copy and Paste Field Codes into Word

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I need to insert some fairly complex mail merge fields into Word based on an external data source (information in a database).  I don't want to do this manually, but somewhat programmatically.

I am fairly restricted in terms of how I can do this. I can't use VB.  I can run a script to gather the information from the other datasource and output the information as mail merge code as raw text.  Then I want to simply be able to take that text and copy and paste it into a Word document and have Word recognize it as merge fields.

For example, I was hoping to be able to use my script to generate the following raw text:

```
{ MERGEFIELD "Price" }
```

Then paste that into Word. However, Word does not recognize that as a mail merge field but just as regular text.  is there a trick to doing this?  Note that I can modify my script to output the text in a different format.

Comment: If you past this text how can Word response it as field?  When you use mail merge word insert field, not text! Word is a program it can not analyze your input! You must insert field if you want a field and text if you want text.

Comment: Please modify your question to say a bit more about the environment you are working in. e.g. are you using Mac or Windows? If so, it is possible to script Word in other ways (e.g. using COM automation on Windows or Applescript on Mac). Does your scripting environment support that? The other way that you can insert field coding dynamically is to work directly with the XML "source code" of the Word document, either working with the component files of a docx, or saving the document as a FLat OPC (.xml) file and replacing the code in there as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Someone will stumble on this as I did and need an answer.

The answer is that you can enter your text as *MAILMERGE field_label*, then highlight, and enter ALT+F9. This will create a field, and I believe specifically a MAILMERGE field. But that takes time, you can't really copy paste fields.

So, the full answer is go to [Windows Secrets](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks) and add the necessary macros to your system macros. This will allow you to copy paste your text fields then highlight the text with the fields before updating them all to fields with your macro.

Comment: Shoot, I shouldn't have used that tag on this throwaway. In case I ever want it back add it to my main account SO.

Comment: I believe it is Ctrl-F9 to insert a new field code, not Alt-F9.  Alt-F9 toggles the display of the document to and from viewing field codes.